# Generar contraseñas con una longitud que le demos como variable

Tags: python, random, contraseña

He intentado varias veces ejecutar el script para que figure en pantalla una contraseña aleatoria con los números y letras que figuran en la lista utilizando random.choice de la librería random(imprescindible usarlo), pero no consigo que se me imprima nada; la consola sale siempre en blanco.

¿Podríais decirme si alguno ve donde está el fallo para que funcione?

El código que he escrito es el siguiente:

```
import random

def crear_contraseña(longitud=8):
    
    caracteres = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "023456789"]
    
    random.shuffle(caracteres)
    contrasena = random.choices(caracteres, j=longitud)
    contrasena = "".join(contrasena)
    print (contrasena)
```

Comment: Llamas a la función en algún momento?

Comment: El nombre del parámetro es `k`, no `j`. Hay que usar `k=longitud`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te respondieron estas usando `choices` de forma incorrecta. Una versión reducida de tu código seria así.

```
import random

def create_password(length=8):
    characters =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "023456789"
    return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
    
print(create_password())
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por fin sale en pantalla!

Answer (score 4):

El problema que estás teniendo es que no estás entendiendo como funciona `choices`, esta función a partir de un array de `N` elementos y una longitud `k` lo que hace es devolverte un array de largo `k` con elementos al azar del array que le ingresas.

Tu array de caracteres se ve así:

```
["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789"]
```

Como puedes ver es solo de un elemento, es decir solo hay una opción de la cual escoger para la función `choices` y por lo tanto te devuelve siempre ese mismo array `k` veces.

Partiendo de esto te serviría entonces tener un array que tenga cada caracter y para esto puedes utilizar una lista: `caracteres = list(caracteres)`, qué te da un array que se ve como así:

```
["a","b","c",..]
```

De esta manera tienes un array con un elemento para cada uno de los caracteres de tu string y cuándo usas choices puede elegir entre todos ellos como opciones.

Así:

```
import random

caracteres = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "023456789")

longitud = 4

random.shuffle(caracteres)
contrasena = random.choices(caracteres, k=longitud)
contrasena = "".join(contrasena)
print (contrasena)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al fin conseguí entender choices jajajja

Answer (score 2):

Hay una forma muy sencilla de obtener lo que tu necesitas y con una línea de código:

`string` contiene los caracteres que tú necesitas, así no es necesario declarar cada letra y cada digito:

```
import random
import string

#Quité la ñ para no tener problemas
def crear_contrasena(longitud=8):
    
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for x in range(longitud))
```

Al llamar tu función:

```
print(crear_contrasena())
```

Produce:

```
0MaU0JjZ
```

Si quieres más caracteres solo ajusta `longitud`

```
print(crear_contrasena(longitud=15))
```

Produce:

```
RuZhA5NL7QQwZ0Z
```

Si quieres siempre minúsculas, la salida:

```
return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for x in range(longitud))
```

Reemplázala por:

```
return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for x in range(longitud))
```

Produce:

```
30bmrqg44fyxdz5
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @María me alegra haber podido ayudar.